# Display array value of selected option

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am trying to echo a value from an array which includes an id and sku number. 
I need to echo the sku number of a selected div.

below is a selected div which shows the data-option-type-id

```
<div class="mageworx-swatch-option text selected" data-option-id="13111" data-option-type-id="166748" data-option-label="3/4" data-option-price="145" style=" max-width: 90px;">3/4"</div>
```

here is my current code which takes the id and sku from the php array and sends to javascript:

```
<?php
$_product = $block->getProduct();
foreach ($_product->getOptions() as $o) {
    foreach ($o->getValues() as $value) {
        $result[]=array(
        "itemoption_id" => $value["option_type_id"],
        "itemsku" => $value["sku"]
        );

    }
}
echo json_encode($result);
   ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
// pass PHP variable declared above to JavaScript variable
var result = <?php echo json_encode($result) ?>;
var json = JSON.stringify(result);
document.write(json);
</script>
```

My mind has hit a wall right now (quite new to this) and any help would be appreciated.

I am thinking along the lines of a javascript if command to see if a div is selected and to match that data-option-type-id to find and display the sku.

I think I would need some ajax in there somewhere?

Would someone be able to point me in the right direction or offer any advice?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend making `result` a JavaScript object rather than array, using the item ID as the keys.

```
<?php
$_product = $block->getProduct();
foreach ($_product->getOptions() as $o) {
    foreach ($o->getValues() as $value) {
        $result[$value["option_type_id"]]=value["sku"];
    }
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
// pass PHP variable declared above to JavaScript variable
var sku_data = <?php echo json_encode($result) ?>;
</script>
```

You can easily look up the SKU

```
function get_sku(selected_div) {
    var item_id = selected_div.dataset.optionTypeId; // value of data-option-type-id
    var sku = sku_data[item_id];
    return sku;
}

function show_selected_sku() {
  var selected = document.querySelector(".selected");
  if (selected) {
    let sku = get_sku(selected);
    console.log(sku);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar, looks like the way to go. Few questions:
1) How do I detect the selected div?

2) How do I get the data-option-type-id from the selected div? and pass that into the function to get the sku? 

Thank you so much for your answer and help

Comment: I assumed you already had some method to select a DIV. That's part of the design of your UI. E.g. you can add a click listener to it, then inside the listener `this` will be the DIV they clicked on.

Comment: 2 --  `selected_div.dataset.optionTypeId` is the value of `data-option-type-id` from the selected DIV.

Comment: Thanks Barmer again for your quick responce, I will take a look at this tomorrow and hopefully have it working! Thank you

Comment: Sorry Barmar, where do I add the lookup SKU code? I think I might be missing a trick here, or just being stupid.

Comment: Hard to answer without knowing how your application works. But if you have a button to display the selected SKU, you would call it from the click event listener.

Comment: `<button type="button" onclick="show_selected_sku()">Show SKU</button>`

Comment: Thank you, basically it is a Magento store with custom options (from a plugin), the PHP part is a separate file to the actual js that runs the options. Would we need to send the Javascript variable from the PHP file to the JS file that runs the options? Perhaps i'm thinking too complected?

Comment: That was just an example. You do it the same way you run any other actions in response to use input. I don't know Magento, I don't know what the code normally looks like. But there's nothing special about this, I think you're overthinking it.

Comment: Thanks Barmar, I was overthinking it, I have it working for some products that have single option, however when a product has multiple options hence multiple selected divs, I run into a problem. I have filtered the array to remove any nulls, but I guess it is still looking for an option id for all the selected divs. Not sure if there is a way we can return all selected div SKUs and join them together eg: skuOf1stOption-2ndoption etc.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll(".selected").map(get_sku).join("-")`

Comment: Thanks Barmar, I get this error in console: Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelectorAll(...).map is not a function. I updated the document.querySelector line

Comment: `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".selected")_.map(get_sku).join("-")`

Comment: now I get this: Uncaught ReferenceError: show_selected_sku is not defined perhaps I haven't put it in the right place? Sorry.

Comment: Functions you call from `onclick` have to be in global scope.

Comment: Hi Barmar, It looks as though the code will always take the first selected div, so I've decided to go a different route and instead of joining them together, I am looking to say if sku is null or undefined then increment it, so that next time show_selected_sku() runs it uses the next id. Do you have any tips on how to achieve this? I know how to increment a number but unsure of how to use this to selected the next selected div. Any help would be hugely appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: Use `document.querySelectorAll(".selected")[index]`, where `index` is the number that you increment each time.

Comment: You are amazing! Thanks Barmar, its working perfect.

Comment: Hi Barmar, don't know if you can help, I have an odd error - if the options are a text field,nothing works - I think its the PHP: `<?php
$_product = $block->getProduct();
foreach ($_product->getOptions() as $o) {
    foreach ($o->getValues() as $value) {
        $result[$value["option_type_id"]]=value["sku"];
    }
}
?>`
this is the text field: `<input type="text" id="options_10286_text" class="input-text product-custom-option required required-entry" data-validate="{&quot;required&quot;:true,&quot;maxlength&quot;:&quot;10&quot;}" name="options[10286]" value="" aria-required="true">`

Comment: That's completely different because you're putting the JSON into HTML instead of JavaScript. You need to use single quotes around the attribute value because it uses double quotes inside.

Comment: Thanks Barmar for all your help, I have got it working completely now, managed to add an if command that finds the option type and doesn't run the code if it is a field.

Comment: Hi Barmar, quick question if you are able to help? The above all works fine, now I need to do the same for a Select dropdown, however the select id's are all different, is there way it can just detect the value of any select? Hope that makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: I don't really understand, but you should ask a new question, not do this in comments,

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your HTML structure, but definitely, if you want to have JSON object you need to use

```
 var json = JSON.parse(result);
```

instead of

```
 var json = JSON.stringify(result);
```

parse converts string to JSON and stringify does the opposite

Comment: he doesn't need `JSON.parse`. He's using `json_encode()` to turn the PHP array into a JavaScript literal. It's already parsed when that code executes.